# Need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | * @type {import(‘../../ipfs/src/core/components/add-all’).AddAll<import(‘.’).HttpOptions>}

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs

I downloaded source code from GitHub and try to run it.
It ran but then came the issue with “ipfs-api” so then I install the latest version of “iphs-http-client” now it pops up a lot of error relating to

PLEASE TELL ME IF THIS CAN BE SOLVE IF CANT TELL ME THE REASON TOO, I'm new to this

```
error  in ./node_modules/ipfs-http-client/src/add-all.js

Module parse failed: C:\Users\lione\Sample\Document-verification-on-Blockchain\node_modules\ipfs-http-client\src\add-all.js Unexpected token (16:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|    * @type {import('../../ipfs/src/core/components/add-all').AddAll<import('.').HttpOptions>}
|    */
|   async function * addAll (input, options = {}) {
|     const progressFn = options.progress
|

 @ ./node_modules/ipfs-http-client/src/index.js 32:12-32
 @ ./ethereum/ipfs.js
 @ ./pages/Org/show.js?entry
 @ multi ./pages/Org/show.js?entry
this is the error log
```

add-all.js

```
'use strict'

const CID = require('cids')
const toCamel = require('./lib/object-to-camel')
const configure = require('./lib/configure')
const multipartRequest = require('./lib/multipart-request')
const toUrlSearchParams = require('./lib/to-url-search-params')
const anySignal = require('any-signal')
const AbortController = require('abort-controller').default

module.exports = configure((api) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line valid-jsdoc
  /**
   * @type {import('../../ipfs/src/core/components/add-all').AddAll<import('.').HttpOptions>}
   */
  async function * addAll (input, options = {}) {
    const progressFn = options.progress

    // allow aborting requests on body errors
    const controller = new AbortController()
    const signal = anySignal([controller.signal, options.signal])

    const res = await api.post('add', {
      searchParams: toUrlSearchParams({
        'stream-channels': true,
        ...options,
        progress: Boolean(progressFn)
      }),
      timeout: options.timeout,
      signal,
      ...(
        await multipartRequest(input, controller, options.headers)
      )
    })

    for await (let file of res.ndjson()) {
      file = toCamel(file)

      if (file.hash !== undefined) {
        yield toCoreInterface(file)
      } else if (progressFn) {
        progressFn(file.bytes || 0)
      }
    }
  }
  return addAll
})

/**
 * @typedef {import('../../ipfs/src/core/components/add-all').UnixFSEntry} UnixFSEntry
 */

/**
 * @returns {UnixFSEntry}
 */
function toCoreInterface ({ name, hash, size, mode, mtime, mtimeNsecs }) {
  const output = {
    path: name,
    cid: new CID(hash),
    size: parseInt(size)
  }

  if (mode != null) {
    output.mode = parseInt(mode, 8)
  }

  if (mtime != null) {
    output.mtime = {
      secs: mtime,
      nsecs: mtimeNsecs || 0
    }
  }

  // @ts-ignore
  return output
}
```

index.js

```
'use strict'
/* eslint-env browser */

const CID = require('cids')
const multiaddr = require('multiaddr')
const multibase = require('multibase')
const multicodec = require('multicodec')
const multihash = require('multihashes')
const globSource = require('ipfs-utils/src/files/glob-source')
const urlSource = require('ipfs-utils/src/files/url-source')

/**
 * @typedef { import("./lib/core").ClientOptions } ClientOptions
 */

/**
 * @typedef {object} HttpOptions
 * @property {Headers | Record<string, string>} [headers] - An object or [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) instance that can be used to set custom HTTP headers. Note that this option can also be [configured globally](#custom-headers) via the constructor options.
 * @property {URLSearchParams | Record<string, string>} [searchParams] - An object or [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instance that can be used to add additional query parameters to the query string sent with each request.
 * @property {object} [ipld]
 * @property {any[]} [ipld.formats] - An array of additional [IPLD formats](https://github.com/ipld/interface-ipld-format) to support
 * @property {(format: string) => Promise<any>} [ipld.loadFormat] - an async function that takes the name of an [IPLD format](https://github.com/ipld/interface-ipld-format) as a string and should return the implementation of that codec
 */

// eslint-disable-next-line valid-jsdoc
/**
 * @param {ClientOptions} options
 */
function ipfsClient (options = {}) {
  return {
    add: require('./add')(options),
    addAll: require('./add-all')(options),
    bitswap: require('./bitswap')(options),
    block: require('./block')(options),
    bootstrap: require('./bootstrap')(options),
    cat: require('./cat')(options),
    commands: require('./commands')(options),
    config: require('./config')(options),
    dag: require('./dag')(options),
    dht: require('./dht')(options),
    diag: require('./diag')(options),
    dns: require('./dns')(options),
    files: require('./files')(options),
    get: require('./get')(options),
    getEndpointConfig: require('./get-endpoint-config')(options),
    id: require('./id')(options),
    key: require('./key')(options),
    log: require('./log')(options),
    ls: require('./ls')(options),
    mount: require('./mount')(options),
    name: require('./name')(options),
    object: require('./object')(options),
    pin: require('./pin')(options),
    ping: require('./ping')(options),
    pubsub: require('./pubsub')(options),
    refs: require('./refs')(options),
    repo: require('./repo')(options),
    resolve: require('./resolve')(options),
    stats: require('./stats')(options),
    stop: require('./stop')(options),
    shutdown: require('./stop')(options),
    swarm: require('./swarm')(options),
    version: require('./version')(options)
  }
}

Object.assign(ipfsClient, { CID, multiaddr, multibase, multicodec, multihash, globSource, urlSource })

module.exports = ipfsClient
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using babel via webpack to transpile the source code and it's failing to parse the async generator function syntax.  You may need to add a plugin or otherwise fix your config.